# Nodejs redirect to https protocol

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, redirect, https

Im trying to redirect user from http//my-domain and https://www.my-domain to https://my-domain
my first idea was to use .htaccess file but, as i understand it doesn't work on Nodejs

This function was my attempt to recreate .htaccess logic in code

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.protocol === 'http') {
        return res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
    next();
});
```

it does work but only in redirecting from http to https
and does not work on the root dir this application (http://my-domain/)
it only works on child dirs (http://my-domain/* to https://my-domain/*)

what can i do?

this is the app.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const 
  https = require("https"),
  http = require('http'),
  fs = require("fs");
  var https_options = {
    ***
    ] };
    
var path = require("path");
const filePath = "temp.html"
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const jsonParser = express.urlencoded({extended: false});
  
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/app/public/public"));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.protocol === 'http') {
        return res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
    next();
});
  
app.get("/app/public/public/styles/style.css", function(req, res){
  fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/index.html'));
});

app.get('/solutionA', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/shop-single.html'));
  });

app.get('/solutionB', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/shop-item2.html'));
  });

app.get('/solutionC', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/shop-item3.html'));
  });

app.get('/solutionD', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/shop-item4.html'));
  });

app.get('/solutionE', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/shop-item5.html'));
  });

app.get('/solutionF', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/shop-item6.html'));
  });

app.get('/Constructor', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/public/public/construct.html'));
  });

app.post("/sendMail", jsonParser, function (request, res) {
    console.log(request.body);

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.Mail_From,
      pass: process.env.Mail_F_pas
    }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
      ***
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    });
  res.redirect(`/`);
});

app.post("/sendMailShort", jsonParser, function (request, res) {
    console.log(request.body);

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.Mail_From,
      pass: process.env.Mail_F_pas
    }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
      ***
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    });
  res.redirect(`/`);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(https_options, app).listen(443);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express runs middleware **in order**.

The reason it doesn’t work when `/` is requested is because `express.static` (presumably) finds an `index.html` to serve which ends the request sequence.

It never moves on to your redirect middleware which will only run if `express.status` doesn’t find anything.

**Change the order** of your middleware.